# TSQL: seemingly empty string

Tags: t-sql, azure-sql-database

As part of an Azure data warehousing project (Running on Azure SQL Server), I'm implementing some business logic to append a new field to a dimension. I found that one of my fields for a particular row returns some data that I'm having trouble understanding.

The column *seems* to contain a blank string (I.e. `''`), but it actually doesn't get caught when using a `REPLACE` function.

Here's my code:

```
SELECT
    <MyColumn> as MyColumn
    , LEN (<MyColumn>)
    , REPLACE(<MyColumn> , '', 'foo')
    , ISNULL(<MyColumn> , 'bar')
    , UNICODE(<MyColumn>)
    , ASCII(<MyColumn>)
FROM 
    <MyTable>
```

And the output in SSMS:

[image: SSMS Output]

As can be seen, the field does **not** contain a NULL value, nor an empty string, and neither `ASCII` or `UNICODE` functions return a valid value. I also tried checking for a space character (`' '`), but seeing the `LEN()` of the field is 0, that didn't work.

I ended up sidestepping the issue by using a `SELECT CASE WHEN LEN(<MyColumn>) = 0 THEN 'N/A' END`, but am curious what value is actually in here. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: @Larnu - DATALENGTH also returns a length of 0

Comment: Which is why I lead on to state your column obviously *does* have the value `''`. I've now, however, moved my comments into an answer.

Comment: @Larnu - You seem to be correct. I used `CASE WHEN <MyColumn>= '' THEN 'foo' END `, which does return `foo`. I learnt something new today. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`REPLACE(<MyColumn> , '', 'foo')` will do nothing. `REPLACE` replacesthe characters within the second parameter with those in the third. Your 2nd parameter is a 0 length string, so contains no characters to replace.

`LEN` doesn't include trailing spaces, so a string with the value `' '` will return `0` for `LEN`. If you want to include trailing spaces, use `DATALENGTH`. IF `DATALENGTH(<MyColumn>)` returns a value greater than 0 it contains spaces, if not, then it has the value `''`. Using `NULLIF(<MyColumn>,'')` will return `NULL` too for any string that is zero lengtt, or only contains spaces.

The fact, however, that both `UNICODE` and `ASCII` return `NULL` suggests that column *does* have the value `''`, as a zero length string cannot value an `ASCII`/`UNICODE` value. This can be evidenced with the below sample data:

```sql
SELECT V.YourString,
       V.StringDescription,
       LEN(V.YourString) AS StringLEN, --Will return 0 for all rows
       DATALENGTH(V.YourString) AS StringDATALENGTH, --Will return varying results,
       REPLACE(V.YourString, '', 'foo') AS StringREPLACEBlank, --Will do nothing, there are no characters to replace
       REPLACE(V.YourString, ' ', 'foo') AS StringREPLACEWhiteSpace, --Varying lengths of foo
       ASCII(V.YourString) AS StringASCII, --Will return NULL for Empty String
       NULLIF(V.YourString,'') AS StringNULLIF --Will return NULL for Empty String
FROM (VALUES('','Empty String'),
            (' ','One White Space'),
            ('   ','Multiple White Space'))V(YourString, StringDescription)
```

which returns the below dataset:

```
YourString StringDescription    StringLEN   StringDATALENGTH StringREPLACEBlank StringREPLACEWhiteSpace StringASCII StringNULLIF
---------- -------------------- ----------- ---------------- ------------------ ----------------------- ----------- ------------
           Empty String         0           0                                                           NULL        NULL
           One White Space      0           1                                   foo                     32          NULL
           Multiple White Space 0           3                                   foofoofoo               32          NULL
```

*The reason `NULLIF(Column,'')` returns `NULL` for a both zero length strings and strings that only contain spaces is because it is a short hand `CASE` expression. `NULLIF(Column,'')` is parsed as `CASE WHEN Column = '' THEN NULL ELSE Column END`. When comparing strings with the `=` operator, a string with trailing spaces compared to one without will be seen as the same value. For example `' ' = ''` would be true. This means that if `Column` had a value of `' '`, then `Column = ''` would also be True, and `NULL` would be returned by `NULLIF`.*

Answer (score 2):

REPLACE searches for a substring in the original string.
As you are searching for nothing, nothing is replaced.

More info can be found here: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_replace.asp

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, I don't think you can replace *nothing* with *something*.

However, there is a lot of different 'invisible' characters, other than space. You can try to copy-paste it to a website which can identify unicode characters (like [this one](https://www.babelstone.co.uk/Unicode/whatisit.html)).

Comment: Tak, Jakob. I tried this, but it didn't show anything when pasting. So the field does contain an empty string.